# Creating a Python module from Fortran source code using SWIG

Tags: python, c++, numpy, fortran, swig

I'm working in a project that involves creating a Python interface for a program written in Fortran. I did some research and decided to use SWIG, first exposing the Fortran routines to C++ and then wrapping them with SWIG. However, I'm having trouble getting the Python module to work.

As an example, I have this Fortran function:

```
function sum_array(input_array, length) result(sum)

implicit none

integer, value, intent(in) :: length
real(kind=8), intent(in), dimension(length) :: input_array

real(kind=8) :: sum
integer :: i

sum = 0.0

do i=1, length
   sum = sum + input_array(i)
end do

end function sum_array
```

With the C declaration:

```
double sum_array(double* input_array, int length);
```

The SWIG interface file I'm using is:

```
%module sum_array

%{
   #define SWIG_FILE_WITH_INIT
   #include "sum_array.h"
%}

%include "numpy.i"

%init %{
   import_array();
%}

%apply (double* IN_ARRAY1, int DIM1) {(double* input_array, int length)};

%include "sum_array.h"
```

This interface file uses the numpy.i interface.

I'm compiling this code (with make) into a shared object as follows:

```
$ swig -python -c++ -o sum_array_wrap.cpp sum_array.i
$ gfortran -c sum_array.f90 -o sum_array.o -fpic -fno-underscoring 
$ gcc -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c sum_array_wrap.cpp -o sum_array_wrap.o -fpic -std=c++0x
$ gfortran sum_array_wrap.o sum_array.o -o _sum_array.so -shared -Wl,-soname,_sum_array.so -lstdc++
```

When I try to import the module in Python I get "NameError: name 'sum_array' is not defined", from:

```
from numpy.random import rand
from _sum_array import *

input_array = rand(5)
sum = sum_array(input_array)
```

From the information I get from help() in the interpreter I believe the linker is not including the sum_array function in the library, which I think is the problem.

Any ideas on how to get this to work?

By the way, advice regarding other tools instead of SWIG are more than welcome, since it's the first I do this and the only way I tried to do it is this one.

Comment: What variables or functions, if any, does `_sum_array` import?

Comment: Do you mean when I import the module in Python? It seems to be empty, I think the linker doesn't find the declaration of the function sum_array...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This time the problem is in *[name mangling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling)*. The fortran sompiler doesn't use it, so the export symbol name is `sym_array`, but later you compile the interface with C++, so the linker expects to see something like `_Z9sum_arrayPdi`. The solution is to wrap the header contents into

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

double sum_array(double* input_array, int length);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

Comment: My bad, that line is wrong, I wasn't using it though, I added it to avoid a warning when compiling the Python interface. When I use the .i file without that line I get "ImportError: /home/manuel/Documents/typemaps/fortran/_sum_array.so: undefined symbol: _Z9sum_arrayPdi
" when trying to import the module in the interpreter.

Comment: It means the dependency for `sum_array` isn't resolved. If you update the post with the correct sources I'd probably be able to help you.

Comment: I fixed the interface file and it's still not working.

Comment: @Manolo I'm glad it helped. I guess you can accept the answer now ;-)